# How to remove duplicates from array if value set for one of the duplicates, else hold null (javascript/typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, duplicates

I need to remove duplicate or empty values (sets) from an array in javascript (typescript) if there is data with a non-empty value on the exact same date. If all the values (sets) were empty on that day, we should keep one value.

#### Example:

```
0: (2) ['2022-12-05', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"
1: (2) ['2022-12-05', 2695.923015841]   ---> Remain because it has a y value (on 5 Dec)
2: (2) ['2022-12-05', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"
3: (2) ['2022-12-05', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"

4: (2) ['2022-12-12', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"
5: (2) ['2022-12-12', 3984.864626441]   ---> Remain because it has a y value (on 12 Dec)
6: (2) ['2022-12-12', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"
7: (2) ['2022-12-12', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 1"

8: (2) ['2022-12-19', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 2"
9: (2) ['2022-12-19', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 2"
10: (2) ['2022-12-19', null]   ---> Remove due to "Reason 2"
11: (2) ['2022-12-19', null]   ---> Remain because no y value on this date
```

**Reason 1**: This member of the array should be removed because we have a null value on the same date (as specified in the x).

```
0: (2) [x: Date, y: value]
```

**Reason 2**: This member should be removed because we have 4 duplicate objects with the same values we only need 1 of them.

#### Expected result:

It would be an array with 3 values (sets).

```
0: (2) ['2022-12-05', 2695.923015841]   ---> Remain because it has a y value 
1: (2) ['2022-12-12', 3984.864626441]   ---> Remain because it has a y value 
2: (2) ['2022-12-19', null]   ---> Remain because no y value on this date
```

Comment: is your data set ordered?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes ordered by date. I'm pushing into an empty array from data I got through rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  ['2022-12-05', null],
  ['2022-12-05', 2695.923015841],
  ['2022-12-05', null],
  ['2022-12-05', null],
  ['2022-12-12', null],
  ['2022-12-12', 3984.864626441],
  ['2022-12-12', null],
  ['2022-12-12', null],
  ['2022-12-19', null],
  ['2022-12-19', null],
  ['2022-12-19', null],
  ['2022-12-19', null],
];

const newArr = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item[0]))].map(item => {
  const findVal = arr.find(_item => _item[0] === item && _item[1]);
  if (findVal) return findVal;
  return [item, null];
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. I make these arrays myself with ```foreach```. Is there a way to do the exact same mechanism when making (pushing into) this array? That is, for example, the first data contains null, but the second data on the same day contains a non-null value. Let's come and delete the null value during the push and replace this and move on to the next day. Or if the second value is null on the same day, don't push it.

Comment: from the same day it will take value (number) if not it will set null

Comment: @MohammadHosseini try and let me know if this logic not works

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array with a single loop and check if `date`

```js
const
    data = [['2022-12-05', null], ['2022-12-05', 2695.923015841], ['2022-12-05', null], ['2022-12-05', null], ['2022-12-12', null], ['2022-12-12', 3984.864626441], ['2022-12-12', null], ['2022-12-12', null], ['2022-12-19', null], ['2022-12-19', null], ['2022-12-19', null], ['2022-12-19', null]],
    result = data.reduce((r, [date, value], i, a) => {
        if (i && a[i - 1][0] === date) r.at(-1)[1] ||= value;
        else r.push([date, value]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```